# Mapping column correctly in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

| ID | date | diff | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 03/08/2023 | 9 | 783 |
| B | 11/08/2023 | 34 | 356 |
| B | 11/08/2023 | 67 | 726 |
| B | 11/08/2023 | 105 | 12 |
| B | 11/08/2023 | 120 | 837 |
| C | 31/09/2023 | 568 | 7 |
| C | 31/09/2023 | 580 | 72 |

Say this is the data I am working on, in this I need a SQL code which will give me the AU_Ids and Score where the datediff is min.

Example, for B it should return 356 as it's CRIF as the diff is min

Comment: What DBMS are you using? It is important to know that, so we know what SQL features are available. Please always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS.

Comment: Have you tried something? Do you know how to find the minimum diff per ID using `MIN`?

Comment: The date doesn't matter here, right? Or have you forgotten to explain what part it takes in this task?

Comment: The data set is an example of what my data looks like but couldn't post it here because of privacy issues.

Comment: I've tried grouping and ordering it and then setting the Limit to 1 but it's only returning one row as result. So I'm thinking of using the rank function but not sure how to.

Comment: Okay. So what DBMS are you using? MySQL or SQL Server maybe?

Comment: SQL server @ThorstenKettner

Comment: What's CRIF, what's AU_ID, your question makes no sense. But i'm guessing you want get top 1 from group for which there are billions of answers already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` per ID. Then only keep those rows ranked #1:

```
select id, date, diff, score
from
(
  select
    id, date, diff, score,
    dense_rank() over (partition by id order by diff) as rnk
  from mytable t
) ranked
where rnk = 1
order by id;
```